# Python scraping stock prices

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, beautifulsoup

I recently saw a post about someone scraping the stock price of the yahoo finance page and the code went like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


name = input('>')
url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}'.format(name)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = soup.find('span', attrs= {'id':'yui_3_9_1_8_1448922823083_37'.format(name)})
print(data.text)
```

I think the code itself might work, but its only the ID that is wrong because it says that:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

What I am asking is how I can find the right HTML tag for the price (for example `google(goog)`).

If anyone has some time, I also want to know how I could for example scrape more than one stock (putting a while loop on the name=input('>) until I say 'stop') while changing the div id, I am not sure how I could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code was written, the ID that is being search for has changed. The following should work, it also shows you how you keep looping until `end` is entered:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

while True:
    symbol = input("Enter symbol: ")

    if symbol == 'stop':
        break

    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}'.format(symbol)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    try:
        data = soup.find('span', attrs= {'id' : re.compile(r'yfs_.*?_{}'.format(symbol.lower()))})
        print('{} = {}'.format(symbol, data.text))
    except AttributeError:
        print("Unknown symbol: {}".format(symbol))
```

This would give you the following output:

```
Enter symbol: GOOG
GOOG = 742.60
Enter symbol: EURGBP
EURGBP = 0.7040
Enter symbol: stop
```

Comment: Hi martins, I'm getting an error message that says "name 're' is not defined", so I assumed you meant r.compile, however, I got another error message when doing that: 'Response' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: I've updated the script, just add `import re` to the top.

Comment: I also have a (probably stupid question), but let us say I go to another page with stock information, how do I find (in the html code) where the price is located? In this instance it was in yfs, but how do I even find it? @Martin Evans

Comment: Go to the site with a normal browser and look up the required stock. Then use `view source` and use find to search for the same stock value.